# How to achieve a matrix from vectorized sum of each row in a matrix with another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, data-science

Suppose we have A as `A=[[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]` and `B=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]` how can i write a vectorized implementation with no for loops in numpy to calculate matrix C as `C=[[6,6,6],[7,7,7]]`?
C is created from summing each row in A with all rows in B.

Comment: how about `np.sum(B, axis = 0) + A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like

```
a = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])
b = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])

c = b.sum(axis=0) + a

print(c)
```

Output

```
array([[6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7]])
```

Comment: Nice. Just to match OPs requirement, I would rewrite your 3rd line as `c = b.sum(axis=0) + a`

Comment: Ahh simple, since you want to add each row of A with all rows B, i just summed on the axis 1 and converted into 1D (since the shapes of array were diff) then simple addition :)